# Error running a startup-script: home environment variable not set in redhat instance running on GCP

Tags: bash, redhat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, startup-scripts

I'm having trouble to understand the shell environement that is used to run startup scripts. What difference with a login session?

If I set a simple starup script to print the env variables:

`metadata

items:
- key: startup-script
  value: ' printenv;'`

I will have something like this:
`Feb 20 15:16:19 xxxx startup-script[1112]: INFO startup-script: OLDPWD=/
Feb 20 15:16:19 xxxx startup-script[1112]: INFO startup-script: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/
Feb 20 15:16:19 xxxx startup-script[1112]: INFO startup-script: PWD=/opt
Feb 20 15:16:19 xxxx startup-script[1112]: INFO startup-script: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Feb 20 15:16:19 xxxx startup-script[1112]: INFO startup-script: SHLVL=2
Feb 20 15:16:19 gceeuw1lin0003 startup-script[1112]: INFO startup-script: _=/usr/bin/printenv`

And if I execute printenv command on ssh session, I can see a lot more variables like HOSTNAME, HOME, SHELL...etc.

I'm trying to install a software at startup (proprietary software) but it's failing because of the $HOME variable.

```
Could not expand the path using $HOME
```

I tried to setup the HOME varibale in the startup script just before the software installation, but it's failing saying:

```
invalid command name "wm"
```

When I try the same installation using an interactive shell, all works fine!
Even better, It works even if I force to rerun the startup scrip from my interactive session using this command:

```
sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup --debug
```

I'm looking for a logical explanation to what's happening? why it's working from the interactive shell and not from the startup script?

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried running the startup script on the automation tab? i see that usually are not used for that please check the [startup script GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) documentation to be sure that you are using the correct script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
printenv
```